# Libm optimised for ARM?

Tags: math, arm, libm

**Is there a libm (libmath) that is optimised for ARM(v6) processors?**

I was looking at the GNU implementation and it doesn't seem to be optimised (but it does have x86 ones). It seems that most implementations of libm do not have ARM specific optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

The closest option i found was using libm for ARM in the AOSP Android's repositories (or the manufacturers if they are providing optimized version of android for your cpu).

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: android.googlesource.com has libm optimised for ARM cores. (Look under bionic or just search the page for libm). Qualcomm also provides optimised libm (bionic) for their krait and snapdragon cores, available at codeaurora.org

Answer (score 0):

There are many math libraries available from the official ARM library. Depends on which application you have.
https://developer.arm.com/solutions/hpc/hpc-software/categories/math-libraries